# Why Thymeleaf for href?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am deploying a template that comprises Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and Bootstrap.

Why does the template need the Thymeleaf component? Normally, Thymeleaf is used to populate the index.html-datatable by receiving data from the controller. But in this case, Thymeleaf is only used in front of the „href“, e.g. like:

```
[...] th:rel=“stylesheet“ th:href=“@{assets/datatable/datatables.css}"/>
```

Why do I need Thymeleaf in this case? Isn't it possible to create such references in normal HTML just without the `th`-prefixes? Is it really necessary to use Thymeleaf here? If yes: Why?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was down-voted - it seems clear enough to me. Just to add to the answer from @metroids, it's not especially unusual, in my experience, to see usages such as `<div th:text="${'hello world!'}"></div>` (to give a trivial example). And these don't add any value, since they don't take advantage of Thymeleaf's ability to process variables. You are not _forced_ to use `th:` in your Thymeleaf templates! For URL links I recommend the overview [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls), if you have not already seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create links without `th:href`.  In this case, doesn't look like there is any reason to use it (since it's a relative link).

That being said, if the link was context relative (starting with a slash `@{/assets/datatable/datatables.css}`), using `th:href` would let you deploy the application to different contexts without having to change the link.  If you didn't use a `th:href` you would have to change the code to deploy to a differnt context. E.g.

```
href="/my-application/assets/datatable/datatables.css"
```

wouldn't work if you decided to change the application context to something like `/my-online-portal/`.

This: `th:href="@{/assets/datatable/datatables.css}"` would work in both cases and produce `/my-application/assets/datatable/datatables.css` or `/my-online-portal/assets/datatable/datatables.css` depending on the context it's deployed to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Does this rule with the leading slash also apply for th:src-tags? Because I found a few examples in my code with a leading slash in the link, but it was in the context of a th:src-tag. Like this one: <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script> ... so could this be the reason why they used Thymeleaf here?

Comment: The leading slash applies to all [link expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#context-relative-urls) `@{...}` (and doesn't care which attribute it appears in). So yeah, both `th:src` and `th:href` as long as you have a `@{...}` expression.